# amazon ec2 instance going to a remote ip using openswan tunnel is up but no traffic being established on the remote ip

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, openswan

I having establishing a vpn tunnel to a remote peer/public ip using amazon ec2 openswan. The tunnel is up but no traffic has been seen on our side or the remote side? Is there I been missing? Please see my config.

My **/etc/ipsec.conf**

```
config setup 
    dumpdir=/var/run/pluto/
    protostack=netkey
    nat_traversal= yes
    plutodebug=all
    plutostderrlog=/var/log/pluto.log
    oe=off
include /etc/ipsec.d/*.conf
```

My **/etc/ipsec.d/con-name.conf**

```
conn con-name
        type=tunnel
        compress=no
        auto=start

        # Define IKE policy
        authby=secret
        ike=aes256-sha1
        ikelifetime=86400s

        # Define IPSec policy
        auth=esp
        esp=aes256-sha1
        pfs=no
        keyexchange=ike
        rekey=yes
        forceencaps=yes
        keylife=28800s

        left=%defaultroute
        leftid=<my vpn public ip>
        leftsubnet=<my internal vpn ip>/32 # 10.x.x.x
        leftsourceip=<my vpn public ip>
        right=<remote vpn public ip>
        rightid=%defaultroute
        rightsubnet=<remote internal ip>/32 # 192.x.x.x
        rightsourceip=<remote vpn public ip>
```

My VPN server is on 10.x.x.x white remote ip was 192.x.x.x

```
Here are the things I disabled.
1. Disable firewall on the OS layer on my vpn server.
2. Put route tables on the amazon vpc.
3. Disable Source/Destination on amazon ec2
```

I have been using telnet to communicate with the remote ip but connection timeout. Pinging the remote side from my vpn server ping 192.x.x.x. The remote server is a CISCO IOS router.

Can you help mo on this? Troubleshooting this within a week now.

Comment: this was solved. the establishing partners has the issue.